# Removing Javascript for iPad / iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, cross-browser, scrollto

I am having trouble with the Jquery scrollto command on iphone and ipads, it keeps flickering every time its used and gets stuck so I have decided to remove the code for these devices but am having trouble doing so.  Here is the code I am trying to use to only show the javascript on a decktop browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
    document.write = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=width=1024px, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 \/>";
}
else{document.write = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function() {$('.nav').onePageNav({begin: function() {console.log('start');}, end: function() {console.log('stop');}, scrollOffset: 30});});
</script>";} // ]]>
</script>
```

The dev site can be found here: dev.greendealcumbria.com

Cheers

Comment: why are you using javascript to create script elements?  Why not just have the function in the else condition?

Comment: not quite sure I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if ((ua.indexOf('iphone') != -1) 
     || (ua.indexOf('ipod') != -1) 
     || (ua.indexOf('ipad') != -1)) {
    document.write = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=width=1024px, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 \/>";
}
else{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.nav').onePageNav({
            begin: function() {
                console.log('start');
            }, 
            end: function() {
                console.log('stop');
            }, 
            scrollOffset: 30
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Was the problem only that he wasn't using toLowerCase()?

Comment: The issue was the script tag but converting it to lowercase is to be on safe side.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, why not just execute the function like below?  Why dynamically create the script element when you could just execute the script?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
    document.write = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=width=1024px, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0 \/>";
}else{
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.nav').onePageNav({
begin: function() {
console.log('start');
}, 
end: function() {
console.log('stop');
}, 
scrollOffset: 30;
});
});
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: its still not working and says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: In addition, why use the CDATA? What year are you working in?

Comment: I am working in Drupal, the previous post from ShankarSangoli has worked.  Cheers for your help tho

Comment: What was the problem?  I am confused.

Comment: changed the code to what ShankarSangoli basically adding a variable to the code